# Boolean function and real degree

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomials

Let $f$ be a boolean function with minimum degree real polynomial representing it be of degree $d$.

Is there a relation between number of zeros $f$ or $1-f$ and degree $d$?

Comment: Yes. More generally, the Fourier coefficients are all multiples of $2^{-d}$.

Comment: ah serious???? how so?

Comment: You can prove it by induction. Should be in O'Donnell's book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exercise 12 (online version) in [§1](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/?p=301) of Ryan O'Donnell's *Analysis of Boolean functions* shows that all Fourier coefficients of a degree $d$ function are integer multiples of $2^{-d}$. In particular, the number of zeroes of $f$ is an integer multiple of $2^{n-d}$.

Moreover, for every integer $k \in \{0,\ldots,2^d\}$ there is a degree $d$ Boolean function having exactly $k2^{n-d}$ zeroes. This easily follows from the fact that a function on $d$ variables has degree at most $d$.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but when you said ‘degree d function’ above did you mean ‘degree d Boolean function’? If so, do you know what happens if we drop the Boolean requirement? I.e. take f to be any real valued function (of Fourier degree d) on the hypercube.

Comment: Right, I meant Boolean degree $d$ function. I'm not sure what happens in general – if you're interested, you can ask a question about it.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I wonder if there still might be a way to relate the 1-norm of f to it’s Fourier degree in this case as well… What if one assumes that the 2-norm of f is 1?

Comment: The question is about number of zeroes. That's not a $p$-norm for any $p$, though it's related to the so-called $L_0$ "norm".